# Calculate just the digits in product of two numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

Given two numbers, let's say in the form of $m=(10a+b)$ and $n=(10c+d)$, is there any way to calculate individual digits (the second digit for example) in the product of $m$ and $n$ without calculating the entire product?

I understand that the product of $m$ and $n$ will be in the form of $[100ac + 10(ad+bc) + bd]$, but I am not sure about what I could do with this next

Comment: What is the problem with just multiplying the two numbers?

Comment: This is not linear algebra. Do read the tag descriptions before using them!

Comment: Sorry about the wrong tag and thanks for correcting it

Comment: @Sam, that works when the numbers are just 2 digits each. If the numbers are 100 digits each and all I want is the nth digit in the product, multiplying the two numbers to do that appears to be very inefficient.

Comment: If the two numbers are $100$ digits, you can simply ignore the digits after $10^{n-1}$ place. Those digits have no impact on the $n$th digit. For example, we have to find the 3rd digit in $186324\times 52343=9752757132$. $1$ is also the third digit in $324\times 343=111132$

Comment: @Sam, although that works, the computation required becomes a function of $n$. I would like the amount of computation to remain the same regardless of what digit is required

Comment: That is not possible. Like Arturo said, you have to check for a carry. However, if you want the $50$th digit, you have to check carry for all previous $49$ digits because each might end up cascading the next one. This then becomes essentially the same as just multiplying the numbers.

Comment: addition of logs ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on whether you have a carry or not. Assuming $0\leq b,d\leq 9$, let $r$ be the remainder of dividing $ad+bc$ by $10$. The second digit is then:

1. $r+1$ if $bd\geq 10$ and $r\leq 8$.
2. $0$ if $bd\geq 10$ and $r=9$.
3. $r$ if $bd\leq 9$.